# Managing replicas per-container rather than per-pod

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

Is there a way for me to set the number of replicas by container instead of by pod?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically you'll only run one container per pod; do you have a specific need to do otherwise?

Comment: I think if you could explain why you need replicas by Container instead of Pod, then you could get more answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there is no way currently for setting the number of replicas by container in kubernetes, and this is unnecessary also.

Pods are the smallest or atomic unit of k8s, it is the most basic deployable objects in Kubernetes. Pods contain one or more containers. Basically the concepts of pod have come as a wrapper around the container. And you can scale up or down of the pod by giving the number of replicas, it's not for container level.

As far the k8s [pod doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) : A Pod (as in a pod of whales or pea pod) is a group of one or more containers, with shared storage and network resources, and a specification for how to run the containers. A Pod's contents are always co-located and co-scheduled, and run in a shared context. A Pod models an application-specific "logical host": it contains one or more application containers which are relatively tightly coupled. In non-cloud contexts, applications executed on the same physical or virtual machine are analogous to cloud applications executed on the same logical host.